# Silverlight 3 developers screwed over by Silverlight 4 centralised rollout

Tags: debugging, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

We have various teams building Silverlight applications within our organisation.   We have just started rolling out the Silverlight 4 runtime, and one development team has reported that they can no longer debug their SL3 app.

Will we need to remove the SL4 runtime on their machines altogether, or can we install the SL4 dev runtime and have their SL3 apps still debuggable?  They are still on VS2008 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have the developer runtime and the client runtime out of sync. We had a similar issue and installed the latest Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime. You can find it at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039

If those two are in sync then your debugger should work not just for 4 but backwards to previous releases of Silverlight.